# EventMachine : Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gcc, bundler, eventmachine

I'm trying to install eventmachine:

```
sudo gem install eventmachine

...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/kuankuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin/g4bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/kuankuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/kuankuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:1344: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin/g4bin in PATH, mode 040777
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

Platform:

```
Mac OSX 10.8.3
Ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

**cc --version**

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

**gcc --version**

```
gcc (MacPorts gcc44 4.4.7_6) 4.4.7
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**g++ --version**

```
g++ (MacPorts gcc44 4.4.7_6) 4.4.7
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**Command Line Tools**

[image]

And, I've tried to change bundle's config:

```
sudo bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it looks like you need to remove `write` permissions from your bin dir:

`chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/g4bin`

it means you won't be able to write to that dir unless you're `root`, but you should not do it anyways

regarding the unrecognized "-arch" option, I believe it's a sort of apples `gcc` extension, so you'll probably need to use some specific gcc provided by apple